# Highcharts gauge not displayed correctly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have an angularjs application in which I display some highcharts graphs.
I display linechart graphs and gauges. With google chrome all graphs are displayed well but on firefox, the gauge are not well displayed.

This is my html code:

```
    <span class="containerGauge" id="containerEnergyGauge_{{energyGaugeCtrl.widgetIdentifier}}"></span>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
            $('#containerEnergyGauge_' + widgetCtrl.widgetIdentifier).highcharts(widgetCtrl.energyGauge);
            energyGauge = angular.element(
                document.getElementById('containerEnergyGauge_' + widgetCtrl.widgetIdentifier)
            ).highcharts();
            var gridsterContainerEnergyGauge = $('#gridsterContainerEnergyGauge_' + widgetCtrl.widgetIdentifier);
            if (energyGauge) {
             energyGauge.setSize(gridsterContainerEnergyGauge.width(), gridsterContainerEnergyGauge.height());
            }
```

And in the console, when I try to display the gauge, I have this error:

> TypeError: "c.center is undefined"

(I don't have it on Google Chrome).

But if I resize the gauge later, the gauge is displayed correctly.

Do you have an idea why it doesn't work on Firefox ?

**EDIT**
This is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tkmwjrp1/4/).

In this you can see that the gauge is created and displayed but we can't pass after: 
`var energyGauge = angular.element(
  document.getElementById('container')
).highcharts();`

So it must have a problem here but I don't know what. Do you know why I can't have the energyGauge in the console ?

Comment: Could reproduce this issue in an online editor (like jsfiddle)?

Comment: No, I didn't succeed to reproduce it on jsfiddle.

Comment: It's hard to find an issue without any example. Have you tried another online editor/sandbox for angular?

Comment: I updated my question with a jsfiddle.

Comment: I checked this and it works fine to me on Chrome as well as Firefox.

Comment: Yes, the gauge is displayed but after we can't do: "console.log(energyGauge)" and I don't know why.

Comment: In your fiddle there is an error in the console before this statement "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined".

Comment: Yes, but it's not the same error when I 'm not with the jsfiddle. My error is: TypeError: "c.center is undefined". But I can't reproduce it on jsfiddle.

Comment: Are you sure that this error is related to highcharts?

Comment: Yes, I think because the error apperas just after "            $('#containerEnergyGauge_' + widgetCtrl.widgetIdentifier).highcharts(widgetCtrl.energyGauge);
"

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce this issue and find the solution.